# ReactNative : Tried to run my first app

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, build, react-native

I tried to run my react-native project but i get this ERROR :

> Aniss-Cherkaoui:AwesomeProject Error_404$ react-native run-android
>       Starting JS server...
>       /bin/sh: adb: command not found
>       Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
>       :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:checkDebugManifest
>       :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0370Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
>       :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugResources FAILED
>
> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> > at index 4
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 10.769 secs
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
> Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
> set up your Android development environment.
> Go to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
> and check the Android tab for setup instructions.
> ```

Comment: `adb: command not found,` have you installed  Android Studio? If not, follow the instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html (Switch to Mobile OS section to Android)

Comment: Flollow the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Yes i have installed Android Studio and i follow the instructions but i have this error.
I run my app from a mac

Answer (score 10):

Just make sure, you have installed sdk and set the paths for sdk and android platform-tools correctly.

Check your .bashrc file or if on mac check .bashprofile.

or additionally you can do is, everytime when you run the app.

Run below commands in project folder.(these paths will work if you followed official RN docs).

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

Comment: I'll add this here just in case anyone runs into this issue and finds that updating .bashrc isn't working. The React Native docs instruct us to put this info into .bashrc. @rajaishwary wisely suggests .bashprofile, but I found that I had all both of those files along with .bash_profile, and it wasn't until I included the above "export PATH..." commands in .bash_profile that adb started working as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably something went wrong during installation, since you are missing abd. 
Try reinstall or maybe run the update first:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/
./android update sdk -u
```

In my mac, abd points here:

```
ls -an /usr/local/bin/

adb@ -> ../Cellar/android-platform-tools/24/bin/adb
```

Make sure you have at least one SDK is installed. (Use SDK manager in Android studio).

Comment: @anisscherkaoui If this worked for you why not select this as the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

> ./android update sdk -u

Was deprecated. Use

> ./bin/sdkmanager --update

instead, if you want to do it via command line.