# Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n .MainActivity

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, adb

Currently I'm trying to run my react native application on my local device using react-native run-android. But I'm getting the following error:-

> info Connecting to the development server... warn Failed to connect to
> development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT info
> Starting the app... 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file. error Failed to start the
> app. Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n
> com.tna/com.tna.MainActivity
> at makeError (C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
> at tryLaunchAppOnDevice (C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\tryLaunchAppOnDevice.js:58:22)
> at C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:104:39
> at Array.forEach ()
> at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:102:48)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\deepali\Desktop\Jay\TNA-1-master\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9) info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

My current node version is 12.14.0

Comment: Did you resolved it I am having the same challenge

Comment: @lewismachilika Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765727/reactnative-tried-to-run-my-first-app

Comment: I have the same issue. This answer solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71908910/command-failed-adb-shell-am-start

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by writing first:

```bash
source /home/username/.bash_profile
```

In the `bash_profile` I have the `ANDROID_HOME` and the `PATH`.

Then, I do the `npm start` and it works correctly.