# Command failed: adb shell am start

Tags: react-native, android-app-bundle

[Getting error while trying to run this command npx react-native run-android for my react native android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiGPA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Usually it happens when Android path variable resets. Try following:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Just paste these commands in your terminal and check if adb command starts working.